# How to prevent cursor from carriage returning?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a simple search field div, but here's the problem:

[image]

*I'd like to prevent carriage returns of this fashion,* using my code (not another library).

Here's my html:

```
<div id="search" contenteditable="true" oninput="searchChanged()"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function searchChanged () {
    queries.search = document.getElementById("search").innerText;
    if (!queries.search.match(/\S/)) { delete queries.search; }
    updateURL();
    updateSearch();
}
```

And CSS:

```
#search {
    width:200px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:#fcfcfc;
    outline: 1px solid #eee;
    focus:none;
    position:absolute;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right:5px;
    margin-top:22px;
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

Comment: you want something like this?..see demo here https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/cc5cygwt/

Comment: @repzero thanks, I'd prefer to disable all multiliine stuff

Comment: Check answer posted if this works for you to disable multiline some hackiness by hiding br tags

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```js
function searchChanged () {
    queries.search = document.getElementById("search").innerText;
    if (!queries.search.match(/\S/)) { delete queries.search; }
    updateURL();
    updateSearch();
}
```

```css
#search {
    width:200px;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#fcfcfc;
    outline: 1px solid #eee;
    focus:none;
    position:absolute;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow:auto;
    margin-top:22px;
    padding-left:5px;
}
#search br{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="search" contenteditable="true" oninput="searchChanged()"></div>
```